# Vue router.push() shows 404 component except browser is reloaded manually

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, vue-router

With `Laravel` `api resources`, I have returned a desired path which I intend a user be redirected to once a record is successfully created.

The challenge now is that although it routes properly with `Vue`frontend from the address bar on the browser, it loads the wrong component of **404** until I hit the refresh button on the browser. Is there a better way of fixing this without using `window.location='path'`?

Currently on my `router` file, I have the following.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import viewAsset from "./components/views/assets/viewAsset";
import NotFound from "./components/NotFound";

Vue.use(VueRouter);


export default new VueRouter({

routes: [
  { path: '/asset/:id/details', component: viewAsset, meta: {title: 'Asset Details ' } 
  },
],

mode: 'history'
})
```

And i'm using `this.$router.push(response.data.links.self );` for the routing, where `response.data.links.self` is the path returned from the `api`

Comment: Can you paste the value of `console.log(response.data.links.self)` here?

Comment: it was `asset/4/details` where 4 is a dynamic id. I tried removing the `/details` and everything was just perfect